# JasperReports with MySQL - Unable to use DATE_ADD in query editor

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I am unable to use date_add in the query editor. I am connected to MySQL database

```
select DATE_ADD(Registrationdate, INTERVAL $P{addday} DAY) from tab
```

I get the following errors :

a. `No viable alternative at input 'INTERVAL'`

b. `Mismatched input $P{addday} expecting FROM`

Any idea on this would be of great help

Thanks

Rathi

Comment: Which data types are set for `Registrationdate` and `addday`?

Comment: Registrationdate is java.util.date and addday is java.lang.Integer

Comment: Looks fine. Does the select work if you send it directly into MySQL?

Comment: Yes it does work in mysql. The point is get the error I have mentioned in the main post. But the report runs and displays the data correctly.

Comment: I wonder about `Mismatched input $P{addday} expecting FROM`. This looks as if Jasper is not translating the parameter in the SQL into a number. Please [edit] your question, add the jrxml and screenshots of the error if possible.